# How to split an interface into multiple arrays of keys separated by type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a simple interface:

```js
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  city: string;
  favoriteNumber: number;
  isMarried: boolean;
  hasDriverLicense: boolean;
}
```

How can I generate arrays with key names divided by type?
The expected result would be like this:

```js
['firstName', 'lastName', 'city']  // string
['age', 'favoriteNumber']  // number
['isMarried', 'hasDriverLicense']  // boolean
```

Comment: Typescript typesystem has no type information at runtime, so you can't generate a Javascript array from a type / interface..

Comment: So it's not possible to do this even by creating a variable that uses that interface and working on top of that variable to achieve the expected result?

Comment: If you have an instance of the interface, and you only care about basic types (string/bool/number) this is possible at runtime. If you care about grouping by interface, things get much more complex.

Comment: I need to do this to do some further formatting, both booleans (which will become yes and no), and date formatting and even changing string names. The real interface is gigantic and I believe doing it that way would save dozens of lines of code, as well as make it easier to read.

Comment: *The real interface is gigantic* that appears to be your real problem. This needs refactoring

Comment: If you have large interfaces, and lots of them.  In theory you could use typescript to generate the AST from the AST you could then create the code.  It would be like another compile stage, but once it's done it's done, and extending your interface in the future wouldn't be a big issue.  Look here to see what the AST looks like -> https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIQDYYPbIN4BQyxykAzmAFwVSgDmBAvkA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an instance of the interface, and you only need to use types available in JS (so, not interfaces), it is possible to build a basic structure based on the types of each property like this:

```js
const example = {
  firstName: 'a',
  lastName: 'b',
  age: 1,
  city: 'c',
  favoriteNumber: 2,
  isMarried: true,
  hasDriverLicense: false,
}

const arraysOfTypes = (obj) => {
  // We'll build an object with types as keys
  const result = {}
  // Go through each property on the instance of the interface
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    // Combine the existing keys and the new key into an array and add it to the result object
    result[typeof value] = [...(result[typeof value] || []), key]
  }
  console.log(result)
}

arraysOfTypes(example)
```

This could be expanded with complex type checking inside the for loop to detect dates/interfaces and then pass their names into `result[typeof value]` in place of `typeof value`, however that is very specific to your solution.